# ios reload tableview in beginUpdates

Tags: ios, tableview

I change the height of a cell (when image downloaded) with method like that

```
-(void)didHeightChanged:(float)imageHeight atIndex:(NSInteger)indexPath
{
   [dictionary setObject:imageHeight forKey:indexPath];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Everything works well with first data, but when I reload `UITableView` with second data , probably `beginUpdates` method doesnt ended and I got issues - when I delete and reload `UITableView`, cell dont disappear, `UITableView` shows wrong cells
 How can I stop `beginUpdates` immediately before reload new data?

Answer (score 0):

You should either call `[self.tableView reloadData]` or `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathWithRow:index inSection:0]]]; // or indexPath if instead of passing a NSInteger you pass a NSIndexPath * to the method.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];

it was called in background thread...